# Простой Python-сервер

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, cmd

*возможно, вопрос задаю некорректно, но я просто хотел бы получить пример такого сервера. Кроме того, мне непонятен принцип работы модуля `cmd2`.*

Необходим сервер, который может принимать и обрабатывать команды, отправленные ему другой программой-клиентом (на `Python`) с помощью `cmd2` и возвращать результат работы. Пример функции, которую должен выполнить по требованию такой сервер:

```py
#import ramdom

def test(a, b): #вызывается cmd2-командой "-test (a) (b)"
    return random.uniform(a, b)

Работа сервера
#################################################################

>>> -test 1 2145 #Высылаем команду серверу
2106.073685868508 #Получаем ответ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Flask & FastAPI

Вероятно, Вам нужен [fastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) или [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/). Эти сервера предоставляют [REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) API в качестве интерфейса для взаимодействия.

## FastAPI

Я больше люблю fastAPI, так как там больше функционала идёт из коробки. Он моложе. Для работы с fastAPI Вам потребуется сам fastAPI и, например, [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) как [asgi](https://habr.com/ru/post/482936/)-сервер:

```
pip install fastapi uvicorn
```

Сервер:

```
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI
import random 

import uvicorn


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/method")
def method(a: int, b: int):
    return random.uniform(a, b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

## Run

Далее, Вы можете выполнить:

```
python app.py
```

или

```
uvicorn main:app --workers=2
```

где `workers` задаёт число работающих копий Вашего приложения, а uvicorn выступает [reverse-proxy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8).

Теперь Вы можете зайти на `http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs`. Или же сразу выполнить `http://127.0.0.1:8000/method?a=5&b=6`, в результате чего выполнится метод `/method` сервера.

## Client

Для того, чтобы обратиться с помощью скрипта к серверу, достаточно воспользоваться библиотекой [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/):

```
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/method?a=5&b=6')
print(r.status_code)  # 200
print(r.json())  # response of server
```

## Встроенный сервер python

На последок, в python [есть](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) встроенный сервер, который я не советую использовать:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```